# Windows Universal - Display images from Assets

Tags: c#, list, listview, win-universal-app

I'm trying to scroll through images in my app, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to populate my list. The images are named using numbers from 1.jpg upwards. If anyone could help it would be great.

```
async private void Exec()
        {
            // Get the file location.
            StorageFolder appFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
            string myImageFolder = (appFolder.Path + "\\Assets\\Images");
            int imageNumber = 1;

            List<Uri> fileList = new List<Uri>();

            foreach (var fileItem in fileList)
                {
                string imageFileName = imageNumber + ".jpg";
                Uri uri = new Uri(myImageFolder + "/" + imageFileName);
                fileList.Add(uri);
                image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(uri.ToString()));
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                imageNumber++;
                }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I have tried to create a workaround and do this without the foreach statement but its crashing when testing if the next file exists: :(

```
    async private void Exec()

        {
            // Get the file location.
            string root = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path;
            string path = root + @"\Assets\Images";
            StorageFolder appFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(path);

            int imageNumber = 1;
            int test = imageNumber;


            do
            {
                string imageFileName = imageNumber + ".jpg";
                Uri uri = new Uri(path + "\\" + imageFileName);
                image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(uri.ToString()));
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                test = imageNumber + 1;
                imageNumber++;
                string testFile = test + ".jpg";
                Uri uri1 = new Uri(path + "\\" + testFile);

                if (await appFolder.TryGetItemAsync(uri1.ToString()) != null)
                {
                    test = 99999;
                }
            }
            while (test != 99999);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your list does not contain any items. Your foreach will never run, as there will be no entries in your list.

You need to go through all paths in myImageFolder-root and add those uris to the list, then you can just use them in a foreach to create images and set their source, for every uri in the list.

Also imageNumber is un-needed then as you will have the URIs.

Prep the list of URIs first, by traversing the folder. Then modify the existing foreach to use those to build image objects.

Also, refrain from adding to a collection WHILE iterating it...

Comment: Thanks Richard, sorry but Im a bit confused. Do I need one foreach statement to populate the list then another to show the images?

Comment: I've tried to do this without the foreach as I couldnt get it working @Richard Eriksson

Comment: Basically yes. Use one iteration to create a list of image objects, based on each URI (file) you find in the directory. Then iterate again over this list and draw them.

Answer (score 0):

I have this working, and not a single `foreach` was required :D Thanks @Richard Eriksson

```
async private void Exec()
        {
            // Get the file location.
            string root = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path;
            string path = root + @"\Assets\Images";
            StorageFolder appFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(path);
            int imageNumber = 1;
            int test = imageNumber;

            do
            {
                string imageFileName = imageNumber + ".jpg";
                Uri uri = new Uri(path + "\\" + imageFileName);
                image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(uri.ToString()));
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                test = imageNumber + 1;
                imageNumber++;
                string testFile = test + ".jpg";

                if (await appFolder.TryGetItemAsync(testFile) != null)
                {
                    test = 99999;
                }
                else
                {
                    test = 1;
                }
            }
            while (test == 99999);
}
```

Comment: If the images are stored in your project you can just use the URI `$"ms-appx:///Assets/Images"`.

Comment: Thanks but I'm going to be deleting and downloading them from Azure so I dont know how many I'll have when the code runs.